# Copy a file from salt master to minions

Tags: salt-stack

Using the Salt python client API, is there a way to copy files from the master to minion without using Salt File Server?

I don't want to use the `cp` module or source `salt://`.

Answer (score 2):

You could create salt state to do this:
Contents of `/srv/salt/copyfiles.sls`:

```
copy_my_files:
  file.recurse:
    - source: salt://DIR_TO_COPY
    - target: /home/DESTINATION_DIR
    - makedirs: True
```

Then run `salt \* state.sls copyfiles`

or

```
ret = local.cmd('*', 'state.sls', ['copyfiles', ])
print json.dumps(ret, indent=2)
```

Test the syntax of the local.cmd above. I haven't tried it on my system, but it should be similar to that.

Comment: Using Salt python client API, is there a way to copy files form master to minion without using Salt File Server. Dont wana use the cp module and source "salt://"

Comment: @bijalcm And why is that?

Comment: It then becomes mandatory to put file or directory to be copied in /srv/salt folder. Cant it be as simple as scp : scp sourcefile targethost:targetpath

Comment: You can only copy down files from the file_roots, ie /srv/salt

Answer (score -3):

Use a different [fileserver backend](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#fileserver-backend).